# module.js:538 throw err; using angular 4

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I'm having this kind of error in my angular 4 project "module.js:538 throw err;". Does anyone know what this is all about?

```
module.js:538
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'swagger-js-codegen'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\zack\Desktop\my projects\accounting-
    project\swagger\generate.js:7:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
```

Comment: `Error: Cannot find module 'swagger-js-codegen'`, need to make sure that's installed and imported correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just do an installation for the **[`missing module`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-js-codegen)**

```
npm install swagger-js-codegen --save
```